# Is it possible to build a grails config property key programmatically?

Tags: grails, groovy

When accessing a Config.groovy property using `grailsApplication.config.myapp.something`

Is it possible to build the property key programmatically somehow? e.g. `grailsApplication.config.myapp. + somethingVar.toString()`

Comment: yes you can, grails will allow (means you can append can't able to modify)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Groovy allows you to use GString expressions for property accesses, so

```
grailsApplication.config.myapp."${somethingVar}"
```

will do what you want as long as `somethingVar` doesn't contain any dots.  If you have a variable that contains the whole config key including the dots then you can use `flatConfig`:

```
def key = "myapp.something"
def value = grailsApplication.flatConfig."${key}"
```

or if the variable is part of the "path" but not the whole:

```
def key = "some.thing"
def value = grailsApplication.flatConfig."myapp.${key}" // gives myapp.some.thing
```

---

or you can avoid the `flatConfig` by using a trick with [`inject`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject%28U,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29)

```
def key = "some.thing"
def value = key.split(/\./).inject(grailsApplication.config.myapp) { co, part ->
  co."${part}"
}
```

The `inject` method calls the closure once for each item in the array we're iterating over, each time passing in the value that the last iteration returned (I've called it `co` as it will be a `ConfigObject`) and the value for this iteration (`part`).  The overall result of `inject` is the value returned by the last iteration.